# General overview of chess algorithms

Tags: algorithm, chess

I am trying to understand basic chess algorithms. I have not read the literature in depth yet but after some cogitating here is my attempt:

1) Assign weight values to the pieces(i.e. a bishop is more valuable than a pawn)

2) Define heuristic function that attaches a value to a particular move

3) Build minimax tree to store all possible moves. Prune the tree via alpha/beta pruning.

4) Traverse the tree to find the best move for each player

Is this the core "big picture" idea of chess algorithms? Can someone point me to resources that go more in depth regarding chess algorithms?

Comment: Your question is probably too broad but the A.I. book by Russell and Norvig is a fantastic introduction.

Comment: You need some sort of heuristic for evaluating boards after you've decided you've traversed far enough down the tree.

Comment: Here's a nice resource: http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/

Comment: Seems like you have a good basic idea of how most chess engines work. Some other things that are relevant: endgame tables (precalculate optimal strategies for a bunch of simple endgames) and opening books (know beforehand what are the best first ~10-20 moves).

Answer (score 5):

Following is an overview of chess engine development.

**1. Create a board representation.**

In an object-oriented language, this will be an object that will represent a chess board in memory. The options at this stage are:

1. Bitboards
2. 0x88
3. 8x8

Bitboards is the recommended way for many reasons.

**2. Create an evaluation function.**

This simply takes a board and side-to-evaluate as agruments and returns a score. The method signature will look something like:

```
int Evaluate(Board boardPosition, int sideToEvaluateFor);
```

This is where you use the weights assigned to each piece. This is also where you would use any heuristics if you so desire. A simple evaluation function would add weights of sideToEvaluateFor's pieces and subtract weights of the opposite side's pieces. Such an evaluation function is of course too naive for a real chess engine.

**3. Create a search function.**

This will be, like you said, something on the lines of a MiniMax search with Alpha-Beta pruning. Some of the popular search algorithms are:

1. NegaMax
2. NegaScout
3. MTD(f)

Basic idea is to try all different variations to a certain maximum depth and choose the move recommended by the variation which results in highest score. The score for each variation is the score returned by Evaluation method for the board position at the maximum depth.

For an example of chess engine in C# have a look at https://github.com/bytefire/shutranj which I put together recently. A better open source engine to look at is StockFish (https://github.com/mcostalba/Stockfish) which is written in C++.